# Why does server not respond in this programme? Client Server Java

Tags: java, client-server

I'm watching a client server java tutorial and in there tutor is developing a chat application. On the package there are two folders. In one folder , there are login ui (code), client connection and main class. In the other folder there are Server connection , Server Client connection (In this class includes to identify client in an unique way, tutor uses random generating number for one client) and main class.

When I'm running the application UI displays, But in console server and client outputs are not showing. Here is my Client code.

```
public class Client extends javax.swing.JFrame { 
private String name,address;
private int port;
private DatagramSocket socket;
private InetAddress ip;
private Thread send;
    public Client()
{

}

public Client(String name,String address, int port) {
    this.name=name;
    this.address=address;
    this.port=port;
    initComponents();
    boolean connect = openConnection(address);
if(!connect){
    System.err.println("Connection failed!");
    console("Connection failed!");
}
console("Attempting to connection to"+ address+":"+port+",user:"+name);
String connection = "/c/"+name;
send(connection.getBytes());
    }

private boolean openConnection(String address){
    try{
        socket =new DatagramSocket();
        ip = InetAddress.getByName(address);
    }catch(UnknownHostException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }catch(SocketException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//receive packets part //
private String receive(){
    byte[]data=new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data,data.length);
    try{
        socket.receive(packet);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String message =new String(packet.getData());
    return message;

}

        //send data
        private void send(final byte[] data){
            send = new Thread("send"){
            public void run(){
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket (data,data.length,ip,port);
                try{
                    socket.send(packet);
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    };

    send.start();
    }


private void send(String message){
    if(message.equals(""))
    return;
    message= name+":"+message;
    console(message);
    send(message.getBytes());
    txtMessage.setText("");

}
```

Server class (This includes in a sperate folder)

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

    private List<ServerClient> clients = new ArrayList<ServerClient>();

private DatagramSocket socket;
private int port;
private boolean running = false;
private Thread run, manage, send, receive;

public Server(int port) {
    this.port = port;
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    run = new Thread(this, "Server");
    run.start();
}

public void run() {
    running = true;
    System.out.println("Server started on port " + port);
    manageClients();
    receive();
}

private void manageClients() {
    manage = new Thread("Manage") {
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                // Managing
            }
        }
    };
    manage.start();
}

private void receive() {
    receive = new Thread("Receive") {
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                try {
                    socket.receive(packet);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String string = new String(packet.getData());
                System.out.println(string);
            }
        }
    };
    receive.start();
}

    private void process(DatagramPacket packet){
            String string = new String(packet.getData());
            if(string.startsWith("/c/")){
                UUID id= UUID.randomUUID();
                System.out.println(id.toString());
                clients.add(new ServerClient(string.substring(3,string.length()),packet.getAddress(),packet.getPort(),50));
                System.out.println(string.substring(3,string.length()));
        }else{
                System.out.println(string);
                }
        }
```

In tutorial ,tutor runs this server code without main method. But It doesn't run in netbeans.

In Server class package main method

```
public class ServerMain {
    private int port;
    private Server server;

    public ServerMain(int port){
        this.port=port; 
        server = new Server(port);
    }
  public static void main(String[] args){
      int port;
      if(args.length!=1){
      System.out.println("Usage: java-jar MyChat.jar[port]");
      return;
}
      port=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      new ServerMain(port);
}
```

In client chat package main method.

```
public class YakaaChat {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
}
}
```

Comment: can you show the main methode?

Comment: is your client `main(...)` supposed to be empty? shouldn't there be something like `new Client("myName","127.0.0.1", 4711);`

Comment: In client package there are 3 classes. Client , Login and main. I already included Client class and at the end of the above main method of the client. In Login ,for the button click , it's like this

    private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
      String name =txtName.getText();
      String address= txtAddress.getText();
      int port= Integer.parseInt(txtPort.getText());
      login(name,address, port);
      
  
      
    }                                              


Yes. It's empty

Comment: ok, make sure your client and server are running... to verify that both are running use either console messaged (logging) or debugging - if you can verify that both are running then check if the client starts to send a message!

Comment: @MartinFrank - When I'm going to run the Server class. I'm getting an  error mychat.server.Server does no have a main method.

Comment: you should not start the `Server` class, rather start the `ServerMain` class!

Comment: @MartinFrank-Thank you very much. First I started ServerMain and then started client login. When I'm putting data into login , in Server console it's not shown. That means data is not passing to server?